# Get Joomla user id returning blank page

Tags: php, joomla

I'm on Joomla 2.5.16 and I want the current user id and group id.

The following code is returning a blank page, why?

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/defines.php";
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/framework.php";

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$group_id = &JFactory::group_id();
$user_id = $user->get('id');

echo $user_id;
echo $group_id;


?>
```

Comment: Is error reporting activated? Does a test output show anything?

Comment: error reporting is set to maximum

Comment: Now, adding this code as a module returns the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method JFactory::group_id() in ..  on line 9

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

if (!$user->guest) {
  echo 'You are logged in as:<br />';
  echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />';
  echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';
  echo 'User ID  : ' . $user->id . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I get the error: Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in .. on line 3

Comment: @Nuno well, you want to include the Joomla bootstrap first as you did in your code

Comment: @Pekka웃, yes with that I get a blank page

Comment: @Nuno then add to the above after the `}`: `else echo "User is a guest!"; `

Comment: @Pekka웃 Still, I get a blank page

Comment: Then something is failing inside defines.php or framework.php and you're not being shown the error.

Comment: make sure you have error reporting enabled. Once done and you import the Joomla framework correct with the correct URL's, use the code provided above and it will work. You simply have yo make sure you are importing the framework from the right location which currently you aren't